# Separating multiple values in one column in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field in an application that allows a user to select multiple values.  When I query this field in the DB, if multiple values were selected the result gets displayed as one long word.  There are no commas or space between the multiple selected values.  Is there any way those values can be split by a comma?
Here’s my query:

```
SELECT      HO.Value

FROM HAssessment ha 
INNER JOIN HObservation HO       
ON HO.AssessmentiD      = ha.AssessmentID
AND HO.Patient_Oid      = 2255231
WHERE Ho.FindingAbbr = 'A_R_CardHx'

------------------------------------------------
Result:
AnginaArrhythmiaCADCChest Pain
-------------------------
I would like to see:
Angina, Arrhythmia, CADC, Chest Pain
------------------------------------------
```

Help!

Comment: It would be better if you separated the upon entry, not upon retrieval. It would be even better if they were stored properly into a separate detail table. Like this it is more or less impossible to separate them (e.g. where does CADC end and ChestPain begin?)

Comment: Do you have a list of all the values that are allowed?

Comment: The values are: Angina, Arrhythmia, Bradycardia, CAD, Cardiac Arrest, Chest Pain, Endocaditis, HF, MI, Other.

Comment: I wish we had control over how the data is stored but we don't.  It's a hosted system and we don't design the DB unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution to this.

The most expedient would be writing a string splitting function. From your sample data, it seems the values are all concatenated together without any separators. This means you'll have to come up with a list of all possible values (hopefully this is a query from some symptoms table...) and parse each one out from the string. This will be complex and painful.

A straightforward way to do this would be to test each valid symptom value to see whether it's contained within `HObservation.Value`, stuff all the found values together, and return the result. Note that this will perform very poorly.

Here's an example in TSQL. You'd be much better off doing this at the application layer, though, or better yet, normalizing your database (see below for more on that).

```
declare @symptoms table (symptom varchar(100))
insert into @symptoms (symptom)
values ('Angina'),('Arrhythmia'),('CADC'),('Chest Pain')

declare @value varchar(100)
set @value = 'AnginaArrhythmiaCADCChest Pain'

declare @result varchar(100)
select @result = stuff((
SELECT ', ' + s.symptom
FROM @symptoms s
WHERE patindex('%' + s.symptom + '%',@value) > 0
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

select @result
```

The real answer is to restructure your database. Put each distinct item found in `HObservation.Value` (this means Angina, Arrhythmia, etc. as separate rows) in to some other table if such a table doesn't exist already. I'll call this table Symptom. Then create a lookup table to link `HObservation` with `Symptom`. Then drop the `HObservation.Value` column entirely. Do the splitting work in the application level, and make multiple inserts in to the lookup table.

Example, based on sample data from your question:

```
HObservation
------------
ID Value
1  AnginaArrhythmiaCADC
```

Becomes:

```
HObservation
------------
ID 
1  

Symptom
-------
ID Value
1  Angina
2  Arrhythmia
3  CADC

HObservationSymptom
-------------------
ID HObservationID SymptomID
1  1              1
1  1              2
1  1              3
```

Note that if this is a production system (or you want to preserve the existing data for some other reason), you'll still have to write code to do the string splitting.